# nested if and statement in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Good Day

I have a excel sheet that has data for 2014, 2015, 2016 and 2017 I have to fill the 2016 data such that it doesnt contain error messages which is #NUM! statement.

so if I have a table like this

```
 2014 2015 2016 2017
 23    25  #NUM!  45
 12   #NUM!#NUM!  65
 #NUM #NUM #NUM   70
```

I need to fill in 2016 such that if it has an error message then take values from 2015, if 2015 has an error message then take values from 2014, if 2016 to 2014 has error values then take values from 2017

This is my current formula but it looks okay but isnt working is there a way around this?

```
=IF(D2="#NUM!",C2,IF(AND(D2="NUM#!",C2="#NUM!"),B2,IF(AND(D2="#NUM!",C2="#NUM!",B2="#NUM!"),E2,D2)))
```

this is assuming the 2016 column =D2, 2015=C2, 2014=B2 and 2017=E2

thanks in advance

Comment: Excel (starting from 2007) has an IfError function you might want to check out https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611

Comment: Define _Isn't working_ do you have an error or is it not outputing the correct answer?

Comment: Also you cannot check the value of a cell from inside that same cell.  If this formula is in D2 it will create circular references.

Comment: I am actually on Office 2010 Daniel.

Comment: The thing is it only ouputs data for 2016 which is in D2!

Comment: The formulae is in cell F2 so I am not calculating in cell D2 if you are referring to this kind of circular reference @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(1E+99,B2:D2)),E2)
```

It returns the last actual number in the range, if none are found it errors and the value from 2017 is returned.

[image]

Comment: This worked wonderfully, so excited thanks alot for your help Scott